# Ansible write on file from jinja file

Tags: variables, ansible, jinja2

I want to lanch a application :

command=/usr/bin/toto --config /var/toto/conf1.json /var/toto/conf2.json /var/toto/conf3.json

the config file are on /var/toto directory

task.yml

```
- name: Ansible find file
  find:
    paths: "/var/toto"
  register: found_files

- name: print files
  debug:
    msg: "{{ found_files['files'] | map(attribute='path') | map('regex_replace','^.*/(.*)$','\\1') | list }}"
  register: file_name
 
- name: Create the Jinja2 based template
  template:
    src: "etc/control/config.conf.j2"
    dest: "/etc/control/config.conf"
  with_dict: "{{ file_name }}"
```

config.conf.j2

```
command=/usr/bin/toto --config {% for item in file_name %} /var/toto/{{ item }} {% endfor %}
```

but, I have get this on my file

/etc/control/config.conf

```
command=/usr/bin/toto --config  /var/opt/msg  /var/opt/failed  /var/opt/changed
```

varfile_name  :

```
"msg": [                                                                                                                                                                        "conf1.json",                                                                                                                                                       "conf2.json",                                                                                                                                                          "conf3.json"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating over the dictionary in `file_name`, which is a task result. If you were to print that out, you would find that it contains something like:

```
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "file_name": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "msg": [
            "file1",
            "file2",
            "file3"
        ]
    }
}
```

So when you iterate over it using `for item in file_name`, you're iterating over the top level keys (`changed`, `failed`, `msg`).

But this is all the wrong way to do it. You never use the `debug` module to create variables; that's what `set_fact` is for. You want something like:

```
- name: build list of files
  set_fact:
    file_name: "{{ found_files['files'] | map(attribute='path') | map('regex_replace','^.*/(.*)$','\\1') | list }}"

- name: Create the Jinja2 based template
  template:
    src: "config.conf.j2"
    dest: "config.conf"
```

After the `set_fact` task, the variable `file_name` will contain a
list of file names.

---

It looks like you're using that regular expression to get the basename
of the files found in your `find` task. There's a `basename` filter
that can do that with less complexity:

```
- name: print files
  set_fact:
    file_name: "{{ found_files['files'] | map(attribute='path') | map('basename') | list }}"

- name: Create the Jinja2 based template
  template:
    src: "config.conf.j2"
    dest: "config.conf"
```

---

Here's the playbook I'm using to test this locally:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - name: find files
      find:
        paths: /tmp/example
      register: found_files

    - name: print files
      set_fact:
        file_name: "{{ found_files['files'] | map(attribute='path') | map('basename') | list }}"

    - name: Create the Jinja2 based template
      template:
        src: "config.conf.j2"
        dest: "config.conf"
```

Before running this, I run:

```
mkdir /tmp/example
touch /tmp/exampe/file{1,2,3}
```

This produces a config.conf file that looks like:

```
command=/usr/bin/toto --config  /var/toto/file3  /var/toto/file2  /var/toto/file1
```

Comment: thanks for your replying, but I get {"msg": "'file_name' is undefined"}, it lack lack of something ?

Comment: If you were copy-and-pasting the code from the second example (using `basename`), there was a typo (`file_names` instead of `file_name`). With that correction, the examples here all run correctly on my local machine.